# mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, mysqli

I don't know why, but this doesnt work.

```
array_unshift($params,$types);
if($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)){
  call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), refValues($params));

  $stmt->execute();
```

Now it says:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given...

So what is wrong with this code?

```
function refValues($arr){
if(strnatcmp(phpversion(),'5.3') >= 0){ //Reference is required for PHP 5.3
    $refs = array();
    foreach($arr as $key => $value){
        $refs[$key] = &$arr[$key];
    }
    return $refs;
}
return $arr;
}
```

The print_r of refValues($params);

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => i [1] => i [2] => i [3] => i [4] => i [5] => i [6] => i [7] => i [8] => i [9] => s [10] => i [11] => i [12] => i [13] => i [14] => i [15] => i [16] => i [17] => i [18] => i [19] => i [20] => i [21] => i ) [1] => 1 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 [8] => 1241 [9] => [10] => [11] => 1 [12] => [13] => [14] => [15] => 432 [16] => 243 [17] => 0 [18] => 0 [19] => 0 [20] => 0 [21] => 0 [22] => 78 )
```

---

Here's the solution:
I just had to implode the `$types` array. So Then the first parameter is a string and not an array anymore.

Comment: and what does make the error is not clear enough?

Comment: @hassan Which one is "parameter 1"?

Comment: @pandaNine `refValues($params)`.

Comment: There are 2 Arrays, is that correct? I'm not sure if this can work.

Comment: @modsfabio Is there any alternative? the array at array[0] contains all datatypes.

Comment: It has to be a single array I guess. As written in my answer: `$params = array(&$var1, &$var2, &$var3);` and not `$params = array(array(&$var1, &$var2, &$var3));`

Comment: @modsfabio Then it says: `Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables`

Comment: Hm, then it was correct before. Maybe the callback stuff is messing things up, but I'm not sure.. Did you try the "normal" way?

Comment: @modsfabio As you see in the title. Its solved. My thanks to you!

Comment: Ah damn, I see.. simple solution... I also wrote `string $types` in my answer (in the quote)... not sure why I didn't notice :P

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's inside `$params`, but `mysqli_stmt::bind_param` expects the second and the following parameters by reference.

> bool mysqli_stmt::bind_param ( string $types , mixed &$var1 [, mixed &$... ] )

Source: [Doc: mysqli_stmt::bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

So you have to change the array values to references.
For example:

```
$params = array(&$var1, &$var2, &$var3);
```

---

In case your array is dynamic, use the following function to convert it:

```
function arrayToRef(&$rawArray)
{ 
    $refArray = array(); 
    foreach($rawArray as $key => $value) 
    {
        $refArray[$key] = &$rawArray[$key];
    }
    return $refArray; 
}
```

Comment: I want to bind the parameters dynamically. You solution doesn't work dynamically, doesn't it?

Comment: You can convert the array, I added it to my answer

Comment: The function I used does the same as yours do:
`function refValues($arr){
    if(strnatcmp(phpversion(),'5.3') >= 0){ //Reference is required for PHP 5.3
        $refs = array();
        foreach($arr as $key => $value){
            $refs[$key] = &$arr[$key];
        }
        return $refs;
    }
    return $arr;
  }`

So the error message is still the same.